# Image extraction using POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI and Java to extract images from the word documents(2007 and above).
The images in the documents appear with the name just below the image. I have to save the extracted image by this name.
I have gone through various articles telling how to extract all the images using getAllPictures() method, but I will not be able to get the name of the image using this approach.

I am not able to attach the word document so I have attached its screenshot  [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLoDh.png)

Comment: Iterate through the text, find a run with an image in it, then grab the text from the next run/paragraph on to get the name?

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr. It worked.